# Existence of edge in graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to know whether an edge exist between two specific vertex?
Is there any function like EdgeExist[g,{v1,v2}]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is  [EdgeQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeQ.html):

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{EdgeQ[g, 1 -> 2], EdgeQ[g, DirectedEdge[1, 2]], 
 EdgeQ[g, 1 <-> 2], EdgeQ[g, UndirectedEdge[1, 2]],
 EdgeQ[g, 2 -> 1], EdgeQ[g, DirectedEdge[2, 1]]}
```

> {True, True, False, False, False, False}

If you need a function that takes a list of (unordered) vertices as the second arguments, you can use

```
edgeQ[g_, e : {_, _}] := Or @@ (EdgeQ[g, #] & /@ {DirectedEdge @@ e, 
     DirectedEdge @@ Reverse[e], UndirectedEdge @@ e})

edgeQ[g, {1, 2}]
```

> True

If the ordering is important, remove `DirectedEdge @@ Reverse[e]` from the function definition.

Notes: As @Szabolcs noted in the comments, `a <-> b` is equivalent to `UndirectedEdge`, but `a -> b` is not the same as `DirectedEdge`.  `a -> b` is treated as `DirectedEdge` only in a directed graph; in an undirected or mixed graph it is treated as `UndirectedEdge`.

Comment: It would be good to mention the non-obvious property that `UndirectedEdge[a,b]` (same as `a <-> b`) tests for an undirected edge only (but not directed), `DirectedEdge[a,b]` tests for a directed edge only (but not undirected) and `Rule[a, b]` (same as `a -> b` and *different* from `DirectedEdge[a,b]`) test for either/both.  This is important when it is not known beforehand if the graph is directed or if working with mixed graphs.  Oh, and this important property is of course not documented ...

Comment: The way the answer is phrased now seems to imply that `->` represents a directed edge but it doesn't ... it could also be undirected.

Comment: Hm, actually I was wrong and it turns out that in mixed graphs `->` is interpreted as strictly undirected.  In directed ones it's interpreted as directed and in undirected ones it's interpreted as undirected.

Comment: @Szabolcs, good points, I added a note covering your observations.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thank you for the edit. (I still use version 9, so could not use a mixed graph to check how it works with different forms of the second argument.)